# How do I set UITableViewCellSelectionStyle property to some custom color?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am developing an iPhone application, in my table view I wanted custom color for Cell Selection Style, I read the *UITableViewCell Class Reference* but there are only three constants defined for Selection style (Blue, Gray, None). I saw one application that used a different color than those defined in the reference.

How can we use a color other than those defined in the reference?

Comment: I would strongly recommend Matt Gallagher's approach over the one you accepted!  Please consider giving it a look if you haven't already.

Comment: The answer's in this post are so messed up. Everyone please ignore the highest rated ones and go vote up the actual correct answers, which are at the bottom.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The best way to set the selection is to set the `selectedBackgroundView` on the cell when you construct it.

i.e.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedCellBackground.png"]] autorelease];
    }

    // configure the cell
}
```

The image used should have a nice gradient (like the default selection). If you just want a flat color, you can use a UIView instead of a `UIImageView` and set the `backgroundColor` to the color you want.

This background is then automatically applied when the row is selected.

Comment: What about for grouped style table views? I just used a rectangle image and it showed through the rounded curves of the tableview cells.
+1 for a great answer.

Comment: For grouped tableview cells you need 4 backgrounds -- top, bottom, middle and top&bottom and you need to apply them based on where the cell is in the group.

Comment: Can you not do this without using images?

Comment: @james.ingham: you could use any kind of view for the selectedBackgroundView. You could use a regular UIView and set a flat backgroundColor. You could use a custom drawn UIView subclass.

You cannot simply set a different tint; this can't be done.

Comment: should do an autorelease on the selectedBackgroundView so it's not leaking.

Comment: This is only half correct. It will only show when the cell is selected, not while it's being pressed.  See Willster's answer for solution.

Answer (score 24):

Setting the `selectedBackgroundView` seems to have no effect when the `cell.selectionStyle` is set to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.  When I don't set the style is just uses the default gray.

Using the first suggestion that inserts the custom `UIView` into the cell does manipulate the cell but it doesn't show up when the cell is touched, only after the selected action is completed which is too late because I'm pushing to a new view.  How do I get the selected view in the cell to display before the beginning of the selected operation?

Comment: This is correct. I need to set selectionStyle to Blur or Gray. None will make it doesn't work. Anyway you can do this by overriding `-setHighlited:animated:` method of `UITableViewCell` class.

Answer (score 13):

If you have subclassed a UITableViewCell, then you can customise the various elements of the cell by overriding the following:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if(highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
}
```

EDIT for iOS7:
as Sasho stated, you also need

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone
```

Comment: In iOS 7 the above solution worked in combination with "cell. selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone".

Answer (score 7):

I tried some of the above, and **I actually prefer to create my own subclass of UITableViewCell and then override the touchesBegan/touchesCancelled/touchesEnded methods**. To do this, ignore all the selectedBackgroundView and highlightedColor properties on the cell, and instead just set these colors manually whenever one of the above methods are called. For example, if you want to set the cell to have a green background with red text, try this (within your custom cell subclass):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Set backgorund
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor themeBlue];

    //Set text
    self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor themeWhite];

    //Call super
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Note that for this to work, you need to set:

```
self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Otherwise, you'll first get the current selection style.

EDIT: 
I suggest using the touchesCancelled method to revert back to the original cell colors, but just ignore the touchesEnded method.

Answer (score 2):

Override didSelectRowAtIndexPath: and draw a UIView of a color of your choosing and insert it behind the UILabel inside the cell. I would do it something like this:

```
UIView* selectedView; //inside your header

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  selectedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[cell frame]];
  selectedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; //whatever

  [cell insertSubview:selectedView atIndex:0]; //tweak this as necessary
  [selectedView release]; //clean up

}
```

You can choose to animate this view out when it gets deselected and will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: This approach avoids Apple's built-in selectedBackgroundView on every UITableViewCell. If you use the selectedBackgroundView, your selection will animate in and out and will also unselected when instructed.

Comment: It would be better to override `setSelected:highlighted:` in the cell and do the logic there if you are going to take this approach so it works in all view controllers. Like Matt said, using `selectedBackgroundView` is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Sublcass UITableViewCell and override `setHighlighted:animated:`

You can define a custom selection color color by setting the backgroundColor (see WIllster's answer):

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if(highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
}
```

You can define a custom background image by setting the backgroundView property:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if( highlighted == YES )
        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seasonal_list_event_bar_default.png"]];
    else
        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seasonal_list_event_bar_active.png"]];


    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated {  
// Set Highlighted Color  
if (highlighted) {  
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255 green:202.0f/255 blue:255.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
    } else {  
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
  }   
}
```

Comment: UITableViewCell has method to set highlighted state color    Here, the code spinnet    
// animate between regular and highlighted state

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Add your Colour.
    SocialTableViewCell *cell = (SocialTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self setCellColor:Ripple_Colour ForCell:cell];  //highlight colour
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Reset Colour.
    SocialTableViewCell *cell = (SocialTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self setCellColor:Ripple_Colour ForCell:cell]; //normal color

}

- (void)setCellColor:(UIColor *)color ForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom color use the below code. And to make it transparent use `alpha: 0.0`

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
cell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.27, green:0.71, blue:0.73, alpha:1.0)
```

If you use custom color and want to give it rounded corner look use:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
```

Also, use this for better animation and feel

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```