# UITableViewCell with background image does not look good

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I created my UITableViewCellStyleDefault styled cell and set its background image:

```
cell.backgroundView = imgView;
```

and it works but the background of the text in the cell is still white.So it hides partially the backgroundView.
I have tried:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.opaque = NO;
```

but none of them worked.

Also the image used for backgroundView has transparent parts but in the cell the are not.
I wonder what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this: [Changing UITableViewCell textLabel background color to clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164459/changing-uitableviewcell-textlabel-background-color-to-clear)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem, I still wonder setting the background color inside tableView:cellForIndexAtIndexPath: method won't work.