# UItableviewcell textlabel background color issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, background-color

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

does not work in iPad3.2.2 but it works fine in 4.2.

can anyone help in clear the cell text background color.

what my requirement is I need to show the `cell.backgroundView` clearly.

thanks in advance

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164459/changing-uitableviewcell-textlabel-background-color-to-clear/2643451#2643451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default UIKit will set the backgroundColor's of all subviews when selecting it.

If you want something differently subclass UITableViewCell and add this method to your subclass:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    [[self textLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[self detailTextLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  [[cell textLabel]setBackground:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
```

Try this brother I hope work fine in very iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in an iPad running 4.3.3.

```
[cell.textLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

this works to me.

Background color is a real nightmare !
good luck